# Communicating information across two android mobile applications

Tags: android, xamarin, two-factor-authentication

I'm developing two android applications.
I have one main application (*let's call this **main***) and one secondary application (*let's call this **2FA***), that is purely used for two-factor authentication. So my idea is that **main** will have a switch that let's the user activate two-factor authentication. The 2FA-enabling functionality needs to be inside **main** because the user needs to be logged in. However, when **2FA** is opened, it needs to know whether or not the user has enabled two-factor authentication (and other variables such as secret key).

My initial thought was to store this as a shared preference. However, this would require me to to store this as a world-readable preference, which isn't very secure because that means any other app can also tamper with the preference (such as turning off the two-factor authentication simply by changing one preference).

Are there any other ways that I can store this type of sensitive information and still access it across other apps *securely*? I realldy need to stress the importance that the information created by **main** should only be accessible to **2FA** and no other apps. Maybe there's a way using SharedPrefences that I haven't though of? Maybe SQLite would be a good option?

I'd appreciate any input that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could try to use AIDL to communicate between two application.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, Content Providers seems to be the best option. I'll update my answer after doing some more research on the security aspectS.